# How to remove error message in the textFiled after submitting the form in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
  Widget commonTextFiled(
      {required String title,
      String errorText = "",
      required TextEditingController controller,
      int maxLength = 100,
      List<TextInputFormatter> inputFormatters = const [],
      required String? Function(String?)? validator,
      Function(dynamic value)? onChange}) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            maxLength: maxLength,
            controller: controller,
            inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
            autofocus: false,
            onChanged: onChange ?? (value) {},
            maxLines: 1,
            validator: validator,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(50.0),
                ),
              ),
              counterText: "",
              errorText: errorText == "" ? null : errorText,
              errorStyle:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              //   label: Text(
              //     title,
              //     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              //   ),
              hintText: title,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: ColorCode.placeholderDefault,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
              filled: true,
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
              fillColor: CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(
                context,
                lightColor: Colors.white70,
                darkColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              ),
            ),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Submit Button code

```
Center(
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 100.w,
                                child: FormButton(
                                    enabled: _isButtonAble,
                                    // enabled: _isButtonActive,
                                    OnPressed: () async {
                                      submitted = true;
                                      FocusScope.of(context)
                                          .requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                      Future.delayed(
                                          const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                          () async {
                                        if (_validateForm()) {
                                          if (await CommonFunctions
                                              .isConntectedToInternet(
                                                  context)) {
                                            BlocProvider.of<
                                                        RequestCallbackCubit>(
                                                    context)
                                                .submitForm(
                                                    propertyId:
                                                        widget.propertyId,
                                                    firstName:
                                                        _nameController.text,
                                                    email: _emailController.text
                                                        .replaceAll(' ', ''),
                                                    mobileNumber:
                                                        _phoneController.text,
                                                    description:
                                                        _descriptionController
                                                            .text,
                                                    agreedForContact:
                                                        isAgreed ?? true);
                                          } else {
                                            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                msg: Constants
                                                    .checkInternetConnection);
                                          }
                                        }
                                      });
                                    },
                                    buttonText: Constants.requestCallBack,
                                    fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            );
```

This is the code I'm using

```
autoValidate:Autovalidate.onUserInteraction
```

to generate error message while the user is typing in the field. But even after submitting the form the error message is showing up. I tried

```
controller.clear() and controller.dispose()
```

but that is not working. How to achieve this? The textfield is clearing after submitting the code but the error message is still showing up. I want the error message to be cleared after submitting the form.

[image]

When email is wrong

[image]

When all fields are right

[image]

After submitting the form and all fields are cleared

Answer (score 0):

So from what i see that you have to use the GlobalKey to validate the fields.

you can declare this one :

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Add the Form on the top of all the textfields :
and give it a key

```
child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
    child: // all your widgets.
```

and on button press in on press add this one :

```
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
// all the error fields will be removed, on button press.
}
```

This is the basic one that i have told you but from what you have described I am crating a example for you based on the code that you provided.

Comment: I'm getting errors after submitting the form as fields are cleared and it doesn't satisfy the validator condition where fields should not be empty. Before submitting the form there are no errors.

Comment: Ok got it, but just to be clear can you add a video or record the video and convert it into gif using any online tool. This will give me a proper idea what the actual issue is.
online video to gif convertor: https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif

Comment: Side by side i will create a example that will cover all your scenarios.

Comment: I added images of 3 different scenarios

Comment: I added Form and key but no use

Comment: Can you add the code of _validateform() and code of where you have cleared the textfield values.